# Проверка аторизации angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Как сделать проверку какую вьюху показывать в ангулар.
Допустим есть директива меню, есть2 состояния, обычное меню с авторизацией/регистрацией, и тоже самое меню, но с доп меню для авторизированного пользователя. 
То нужно создать 2 директивы, отдельно для авторизированного и не авторизированного пользователя ?
Что то вроде:

```
<menu-dir ng-if="!isUser()">
<menu-auth-dir ng-if="isUser()">
```

Или подскажите как обычно решают такую проблему, и тоже самое с действиями ?

Comment: У нас обычно решает сервер, какое меню\привилегии\роли имеет пользователь. И соответственно, отдает готовые данные и view. Т.е. на стороне клиента меню\привилегии\роли не проверяются.

Answer (score 1):

Можно передавать параметр напрямую в директиву.

```
<menu-dir is-auth="!isUser()">
```

Уже в коде директивы на основе параметра определяете, что показывать, а что нет. Но в любом случае проверка разрешения на действие должна быть продублирована на сервере.